# Windows and Ubuntu on separate SSD's, but only one can be found depending on hardware setup

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I'm relatively new to using Ubuntu/Linux so I'm sorry if I'm missing something simple or something goes over my head.

I had Windows installed on my computer on the main SSD (SSD1) which is a 1 TB SSD. I decided I wanted to fiddle around with Ubuntu but when trying to partition the drive I ran into problem after problem. I decided to just use my second SSD (SSD2) for Ubuntu and got everything I needed off of it. In order to install in the simplest way I unplugged (power + SATA) SSD1 and wiped SSD2 to install Ubuntu. The installation finally worked and I thought my woes were over.

Now whenever I have SSD1 + SSD2 plugged in it will boot Ubuntu, but skips the grub menu (and when I force it to open with Esc there is no Windows option). If I unplug SSD2 and leave SSD1 plugged in, it will boot up Windows with no problem.

Ultimately I'd like to have the grub menu appear (or really any menu that allows me to choose which OS I want to use) when booting and have the option to use both Windows or Ubuntu without having to open the computer and unplugging one of the SSD's.

Thank you.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Thanks for the post, unfortunately none of those seem to have the answer to my specific problem.